# Duplicate files in Trash after upgrade to Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, trash, thunar

After upgrading Xubuntu 19.10 to Xubuntu 20.04, every time I move a file to Trash (through Thunar), two copies of that file appear in Trash. When I choose to empty the Trash, I get the message "Could not delete file "/run/timeshift/backup/.Trash-1000/files/..." (... stands for filename) or "Could not delete file "/mnt/Data/.Trash-1000/files/..." and the choice to ignore, skip, retry, etc. In any case, the Trash is emptied (i.e., both the real file as well as the copy disappear from Trash).

I uninstalled timeshift, but the problem persists. When I restart the computer, for the first few minutes Trash is emptied without any error messages. This only happens for files moved to Trash from that particular disk (mounted as Data). I deleted the partition and reformatted it, but the problem did not go away. Any ideas?